# TypeError: "cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object", but with a TWIST

Tags: python, scrapy, typeerror

This a Scrapy project, so *response* is a result of scrapy.Request()

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

def start_requests(self):

    yield scrapy.Request(url="someurl", callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    model = response.css('div.main div.title::text').extract_first()
    model_match = re.match(b'\d', model)
```

and I get:

```
TypeError: cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object
```

OK, so I change my pattern

```
    model_match = re.match(r'\d', model)
```

But still get:

```
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

From the other hand, everything works as a charm on the another machine, so I assume something is wrong with my current setup. I would appreciate your advice on where do I start looking first.
Thanks!

Comment: can you post how are you getting your `response` object?

Comment: I've added some code to clarify, hope it makes sense. Also, my request returns some non-ascii characters, not sure if it makes a difference

Comment: Could you post url you're crawling and full traceback?

Comment: @Granitosaurus As soon as I got two tracebacks side to side in the editor I realized that they are related to different sections of the code. So there wasn't a problem at all, which is pretty embracing. Thanks for your time, guys!